# Postgresql database crashes

Tags: postgresql

When I use truncate table, and application uses the same table at the same time, my db crashes all, or the table crashes only.
Why is this happening?
The application function, that uses db, does it with transaction.

Comment: This belongs to  dba.stackexchange.com but you will need to provide **much** more detail on the "crash". E.g. exact and complete error message, contents of the Postgres log file when the crash happened. **exact** Postgres version, operating system and version, the SQL statement that caused the crash and the DDL for all objects used in the statement. Additionally: tables can't "crash". So most probably there is something completely different going on than a "crash"

Comment: what is the actual error and/or error stack that you get. What part in your application fails and with which error?